# Intento guardar varias instancias en un array con un bucle en javascript

Tags: javascript

Mi problema es que en el array resultante, el primer elemento comienza en la posicion 1 y la 0 aparace undefined como si se hubiera saltado una posicion ya que el ultimo objeto que deberia de estar en la ultima posicion se pierde

Espero que me puedan ayudar en eso, es algo inusual

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! sin ver que haces, imposible ayudarte...